# prevent running command on remote computer from terminating when disconnect

Tags: remote-access

Suppose I ssh to a remote machine and run this `ping www.google.com`, when I disconnect, this will stop.

Is there anyway for me to login, run a command, then logoff/disconnect but still keep the command running?

Comment: You could let it run in the background by adding & at the end of your command eg. ping www.google.com &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is to use

```
 nohup command >log 2>error-log &
```

You have to background the process (&) and make sure it won't hang up trying to write messages to the terminal. The nohup makes sure it doesn't get signals (like SIGHUP) when the parent process (terminal session) closes.

By the way, if you read ping's man-page you'll see that it is considered a bad idea to leave it running like that.

```
   This  program  is  intended for use in network testing, measurement and
   management.  Because of the load it can impose on the  network,  it  is
   unwise  to use ping during normal operations or from automated scripts.
```

Comment: Thanks! I've read about ping. But all I meant was that I had a command that needed to run for a long time, but which doens't need user input/babysitting. Couldn't come up with a better example, so I chose ping ...

Answer (score 0):

`screen` and  `tmux` can persist disconnected sessions.

they'll run on ptetty much anything that accepts SSH connections, (you didn't say what OS)
but they're optional packages so you may have to install them.

Comment: If it's a simple command and you run it manually, you can also just put an ampersand (&) behind it in most cases. Like: "ping 8.8.8.8 &".